# Can't seem to get a window from PYQT5 in Pycharm (macOS Big Sur)

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, pycharm, pyqt5

I am using macOS Big Sur beta currently. I have been able to download the libraries via Pycharm 2020.1.2 however, when running my program, no window appears to show what I've been working on.

Example:

Here is a simple line of code I've gotten as an example.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

app = QApplication([])
label = QLabel('Welcome to PYQT5 Tester')
label.show()
app.exec_()
```

When I run the app, there are no errors and the sole description is my file directory. I am really confused to if I haven't installed anything but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some of this informations should help you: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4627

Answer (score 3):

Went down to PyQt5==5.13 and it's working for me now.

Comment: Can confirm moving down to 5.13 also worked for me. Would be nice to know if anyone has any info on WHY, or where we can check if Riverbank has plans to fix the compatibility in an uncomming release (5.15.2 is in dev right now). https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download